# Pentaho not running after removing users

Tags: pentaho

I removed all default user of pentaho after creating new user with all rights. Now the server won't start with following error:

```
misc-org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.defaultcontent.DefaultContentSystemListener: User not found; nested exception is org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User not found
May 06, 2014 11:53:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 06, 2014 11:53:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/pentaho] startup failed due to previous errors
11:53:34,900 ERROR [PluginRepositoryResourceAccess] Unable to get repository as system.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The userCache Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
```

I tried [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?75428-User-not-found-when-tring-to-access-to-the-solution-repository) but I couldn't find console.xml file in pentaho5. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, if I delete all user except admin it works fine. Admin user is required.